# SQL Server - Performance of increase decimal precision/scale

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know what is the impact of modifying a SQL Server decimal column.

By example I have *Decimal(12,2)* column and I want to change it to *Decimal(13,3)*

Facts:

- I won't loose any data (increasing the precision + scale won't throw any warning).
- I'll still have a 9 bytes field. (See MSDN references: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

**Question 1: If I have over 10 millions or more row, how it will react?**

**Question 2: Is it going to take a lot of time to upgrade the precision+scale or will it be instantaneous (I am talking about performance of the change being applied)?**

I actually tried on small table and it seems to be instantaneous, but I want to be sure before doing it on a huge table.

Comment: shouldn't be an issue if you're increasing precision. Can't you restore a previous backup to your local machine to test? BTW are you talking about performance of the change being applied or whether query execution will be affected after? I'm guessing the first.

Comment: I am talking about the performance of the change being applied. Btw, I cannot get a backup, the database is really too huge.

Comment: @Nordes If your database is that big, and business-critical, do you have a disaster recovery plan in place? If so, could you use one of the servers allocated to that to try this on?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I've actualy asked the DBA if I could do it on the pre-prod environment before they refreshes it. So I am waiting. But they might give me a No-Go ;).

Comment: @Nordes Tell your DBA that some random person on StackOverflow told you it was ok. ;)  (and then ask him if he'd prefer you to do it on a live system instead)

Comment: @AdrianWragg lol ;)... Look at the answer of Raj bellow. I cannot do that or I am going to be killed hehe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary representation is different so it needs to perform a logged update to each row.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(1 AS Decimal(12,2)) AS VARBINARY), 
       CAST(CAST(1 AS Decimal(13,3)) AS VARBINARY)
```

Returns

```
0x0C02000164000000
0x0D030001E8030000
```

Answer (score 2):

It certainly is not going to be instantaneous. I just tried on a table with 175 million rows of data in my test DB. The query has been running for the past 10 minutes and is still in progress.

Also, if there are any indexes on this column, you will have to drop and recreate those indexes, which will add to the total time required.

Raj

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No I don't have any indexes on my decimal columns.